# multicolumn, multirow problem

Tags: multirow

I am trying to have this type of table using multirow, multicolum. But no luck.[image]

Here is the code I have tried but getting error.

```
\begin{table}
      \caption{Total Task Completion Time}
      \label{fig:taskCompletionTime}
      \begin{tabular}{ccccccc}
        \toprule
          \multicolumn{1}{c}{Interface (i)} &
          \multicolumn{1}{c}{Interface (j)} &
          \multicolumn{1}{c}{Mean Difference (i-j)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Std. Error} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Sig.} \\
        \midrule
        \multirow{1}{*}{Traditional-Timed-VidComm}
        \bottomrule
      \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to end the last line with `\\` before `\bottomrule`:

```
    \multirow{1}{*}{Traditional-Timed-VidComm}\\
    \bottomrule
```

However, why do you use `\multicolumn{1}{c}{..}`? You already have a centered column defined?

Comment: what a silly mistake. Thanks!
Oh I just copied code from somewhere! thanks for mentioning :)